# Javascript threading model for multiple Websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a javascript client which has to communicate with more than 1 than one Websocket server. One of these servers sends small, high frequency payloads that I can process quickly, while the other sends larger, low frequency data that takes a long time to process:

```
this.hifreq = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.2:4646/hi");
this.hifreq.onmessage = this.onHighfreqMessage;

this.lofreq = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.3:4646/lo");
this.lofreq.onmessage = this.onLowfreqMessage;
```

I cannot find any precise documentation indicating how the threading model will work. Everybody seems to be saying that the browser model is single threaded, so there is no way I can receive two payloads and work on them simultaneously, but I can't find the single concrete documentation that says that. Is that correct? and if so, is there a way to handle the messages on different threads?

I want to make the page as responsive as possible, and my current understanding is that once I start processing the large payload, I cannot update the page in the background with the high frequency data (which I can process almost instantaneously).

I am coming form a C++/Java background, so I am trying to understand what my options are here.

Comment: check out this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker

Comment: It seems like you implying that a Websocket (like above) will not automatically handle messages on a separate thread, and that I would have to create a WebWorker to process in a separate thread. Is that correct?

Comment: That's right. JavaScript is always single threaded.

Comment: Really nice example on the page you linked

Comment: Post a quick answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Web Worker to do heavy background task. Note that JavaScript still appears to be single threaded. You have no access to window object of the page in the worker thread. You should use `postMessage` and `onmessage` on `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope` to communicate with the main script.